# OBD2 Simulator: unable to send AT-commands

Tags: c#, mobile, wifi, obd-ii, elm327

I have been trying to use OBDSIM (https://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/obdsim.html) to simulate a car. My plan is to write a mobile application to read data from a real car using an OBD2 dongle. For testing purposes, using a simulator is the best way to get started I think. I have virtualisation software to enable COM-ports, so that issue has been tackled.

I am able to start OBDSIM, but then it keeps throwing out samples and I can not send any AT-commands in the command prompt console because of that.

The question is if anybody knows how to run AT-commands using OBDSIM or if there are any alternatives that work in the same way as OBDSIM?

Any advice about a better way to actually develop software to make this possible is welcome! I am unsure if buying the OBD2 dongle at this stage helps, because the range to my car might be too far (10 meters with walls in between). I am also unsure if I should buy a wi-fi or bluetooth variant of the dongle.

Thanks in advance,

Ramon

Answer (score 2):

After doing a lot of research on the internet, I found a great emulator here:
https://github.com/Ircama/ELM327-emulator

Further, I found good software to turn on a COM-port correctly on Windows 10:
https://www.eltima.com/virtual-com-port-windows-10/

You will need to turn on COM-port 3 and 4 as a pair. The emulator works on COM3 by default.

After turning on the emulator and running this example library it worked:
https://github.com/DarthAffe/OBD.NET

Now I can create my own library and follow the code of the library to achieve what I want.

The following links helped to understand OBD2 better:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs
- https://www.csselectronics.com/screen/page/simple-intro-obd2-explained/language/en

I hope this helps someone else in the future!

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing!

Comment: I don't think the emulator and the ODB.NET are compatible. When I ran the async one, it does not return any data.